# Rstudio not working on my Ubuntu 16 virtual machine

Tags: rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, glx

When I try to run Rstudio Desktop (1.4) on my virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.4), Rstudio crashes and gives the error:

```
ERROR:gl_surface_glx_gt.cpp(141) GLX 1.3 or later is required.
```

I tried to follow the instructions on this page: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:development:glx-xlib-workaround, but can not get past the meson -D configuration in the Ubuntu terminal. At this point I get the error message: 'ERROR: Problem encountered: gallium-xlib conflicts with any dri driver'

I googled and tried everything that I could possibly find (similar questions as https://community.rstudio.com/t/x2go-and-rstudio/29704/2), but no success yet.
Obviously the upgrade to a higher GLX version is the cause, but I can not upgrade it.
Is anyone familiar with the error and what is actually causing it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using R version 3.4.4